# Apache Spark filter elements

Tags: scala, foreach, filter, apache-spark

I have two RDDs: `points` and `pointsWithinEps`. Their content is in the figures below:
[image]
[image]

Vector is representing `x, y` coordinate. `pointsWithinEps` represent two points and distance between them. I want to loop all `points` and for every point filter only that elements which are in the `pointsWithinEps` as `x` (first) coordinate. So for the first point it will give `[0]` and `[1]` vectors from `pointsWithinEps`. I have following code:

```
for (i <- 0 until points.count.toInt) {
  val p = points.take(i + 1).drop(i)
  val currentPointNeighbours = pointsWithinEps.filter {
    case ((x, y), distance) =>
      x == p
  }
  currentPointNeighbours.foreach(println)
  println("----")
}
```

It does not work correctly. What is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it efficiently if you transform your RDDs to K-V RDDs, and then do join on key. For points key is point itself, for distances key is first point

```
  import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._

  type Point = DenseVector
  type Distance = ((Point, Point), Double)

  val points: RDD[Point] = ???
  val pointsWithinEps: RDD[Distance] = ???

  // Prepare Tuple2 RDD to enable spark tuple functions
  val pointsToKV: RDD[(Point, Unit)] = points.map(p => p -> ())
  val distance: RDD[(Point, Distance)] = pointsWithinEps.map(distance => distance._1._1 -> distance)

  // Join points with distance
  val filtered: RDD[Distance] = pointsToKV.join(distance) map (_._2._2)
```